# Set the new-tab page in Firefox

Tags: firefox, homepage

A couple of months ago, I configured Firefox to load a local html file containing my commonly-used links whenever I open a new tab

This week I've been trying to find where I set this up.  I cannot find this setting anywhere in the Firefox options.  Somewhere there is (or was) a dialog box with an item that said something like 'Page to load in new tab'.  Where was it?  Could Mozilla have removed it in the latest upgrade?

I'm not using any extensions but LastPass, so it's not controlled by an extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open a new tab and type `about:config` in the address bar
- Click "I'll be careful"
- Select `browser.newtab.url`
- Double click on that line and change the value to the address of your local file

Comment: An additional note:  if you need to hunt through all the items in the about:config list, enter any part of it that you know in the Search box.  The list will be whittled down to only the items that contain your search term.